# Como faço para usar um mixin criado em outro arquivo?

Tags: less

Tenho uma dúvida sobre uso de *mixin* do less em diferentes folhas de estilo.

Eu tenho 2 folhas de estilos iniciais: reset.less e styleguide.less

Gostaria de saber como posso no styleguide.less definir um *mixin* `title`.

E no reset.less apenas o utiliza-lo.

Exemplo:

**styleguide.less**

```
.title() {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**reset.less**

```
.h1 {
  .title();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa referenciar o arquivo onde encontra-se esse *mixin*, fazendo o `@import`.

```css
/* mixin.less */
.title(){
    text-decoration: none
}

/* reset.less */
@import "mixin.less";

.title {
    .title();
}
```

---

Uma forma de organizar seus arquivos é criar uma estrutura semelhante a esta:

```css
- less
|- build
|    |- mixin.less
| - variables.less
| - functions.less

... outros *.less
```

Assim você pode manter os arquivos separados, mantendo em cada .less uma função específica. O único arquivo do qual será gerado o CSS é aquele que estiver no diretório *build*. Um exemplo, de separação utilizando a estrutura acima:

```css
/* variables.less */
@background-color: #fff;
@font-color: #333;
```

Esse arquivo não tem conhecimento de nenhum outro *.less*.
Já o `functions.less` tem acesso ao arquivo de variáveis para utilizá-las nas funções, por exemplo:

```css
@import "variables.less";

.transform(@arguments){
    -webkit-transform: @arguments;
        -ms-transform: @arguments;
            transform: @arguments;
}

.paint-div(){
    color: @font-color;
    background: @background-color
}
```

E finalmente o arquivo de *build*. Este pode ignorar o arquivo de variáveis acessar somente ao arquivo de funções:

```css
@import "../functions.less"; /* subindo um nível pois ele está dentro do diretório 'build'*/

.main {
    .paint-div();
}

.main {
    & a {
        .transform(translateX(200px) rotate(6deg));
    }
}
```

Quando compilado, a folha de estilos:

```css
.main {
  color: #333333;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.main a {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200px) rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: translateX(200px) rotate(6deg);
          transform: translateX(200px) rotate(6deg);
}
```

Comment: valeu, deu certo aqui! Eu tinha medo de fazer o import e dublicar no meu grunt, já que to pegando *.less. Mas deu certo, valeu!